# Grouping Data on php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data on mysql where user registred the data with various district. Now I need to group them on the basis of district and present them on chart. I've got refrence from google chart. My probles is how to group the number of data into sets.

Example:

```
user1 district1
user2 district2
user3 district1
user4 district1
user5 district2
```

now I need the data like:

```
district1=>3
district2=>2
```

Data are retrieved from MySql. Could any one help with php code or any sql query to retrieve the data like this, so that I could pass the object on js to form a graph.

Comment: So you need it in an array with user# as a value and district as a key?

Comment: No I need District as value and its count as a key. Like there are 3 user from district 1 and 2 user from district 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select from the database the district and user count, then group them by the districts:

```
SELECT COUNT(user),district FROM yourtable GROUP BY district;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (of course you need to adjust the column and table names to your needs):

```
SELECT `disctrict_field`, COUNT(*) FROM `table` GROUP BY `disctrict_field`
```